# Avoid inserting duplicates when working with composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, composite-primary-key

I'm writing a query in SQL that transfers data from an Acces DB to a new SQL server management DB.
This transfer is a one time only, so I do not have to worry about the code being super generic.

I'm trying to insert data from a couple of tables (including tables from the Acces DB), but get an error about duplicates on the composite primary key.

My problem is that I can't see why my uses of distinct does not prevent those duplicates.

The table I want to insert into is constructed as so:

[image: ComponentSupplier table]

The code I'm trying to execute is written as followed:

```
-- Insert into ComponentSupplier for [Supplier 1]

insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 1 order no], a.[PDF Data 1 sheet link], a.[Supplier 1 LF], '1'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 1]

-- Insert into ComponentSupplier for [Supplier 2]

insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 2 order no], a.[PDF Data 2 sheet link], a.[Supplier 2 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 2]

-- Insert into ComponentSupplier for [Supplier 3]

insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 3 order no], a.[PDF Data 3 sheet link], a.[Supplier 3 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 3]

-- Insert into ComponentSupplier for [Supplier 4]

insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 4 order no], a.[PDF Data 4 sheet link], a.[Supplier 4 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 4]

-- Insert into ComponentSupplier for [Supplier 5]

insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 5 order no], a.[PDF Data 5 sheet link], a.[Supplier 5 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 5]

-- Insert into ComponentSupplier for [Supplier 6]

insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 6 order no], a.[PDF Data 6 sheet link], a.[Supplier 6 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 6]
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` means that there will be no rows with exactly the same values across *every* column. It won't stop 2 columns have the same values. `0,0,1,2,3,4` and `0,0,1,2,3,5` are 2 `DISTINCT` data set, but would fail the duplciate key constraint in your table, as the first 2 columns are both `0` in both sets (so are duplicates). What you need to do to fix this, we don't know; we don't know your data or your expected results. The fact that you are migrating the data, however, and using `DISTINCT` seems odd to start with; that would (possibly) result in data loss.

Comment: @Larnu that makes sense to me. I indeed do no want to lose any data during the migration. Is there any way to check if just the two column combinations already exists?

Comment: You could use a windows `COUNT` and a CTE.

Comment: @loragi - you have conflicting goals. You want to normalise the data, but you've also said you don't want to lose any data. You need to decide which goal is more important. If it's normalization, then you need to *devise a strategy* for dealing with the unnormalized source data and then tell *us* (and SQL Server, via the query we write) what that strategy is.

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct` de-duplicates based on *all* the columns in the `select`.

The issue could be because you are inserting record using multiple `insert..selects`, you could try something like this to ensure records are de-duplicated correctly.

The `distinct` will de-dup withing each `select`, and the `union` will de-dup across the `select` statements:

```
insert into CDB2020.dbo.ComponentSupplier
(
    Supplier_ID,
    BK_ID,
    Part_ID,
    Datasheet,
    LF,
    Preferred
)
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 1 order no], a.[PDF Data 1 sheet link], a.[Supplier 1 LF], '1'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 1]
union
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 2 order no], a.[PDF Data 2 sheet link], a.[Supplier 2 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 2]
union
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 3 order no], a.[PDF Data 3 sheet link], a.[Supplier 3 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 3]
union
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 4 order no], a.[PDF Data 4 sheet link], a.[Supplier 4 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 4]
union
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 5 order no], a.[PDF Data 5 sheet link], a.[Supplier 5 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 5]
union
select distinct s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, a.[Supplier 6 order no], a.[PDF Data 6 sheet link], a.[Supplier 6 LF], '0'
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 6]
```

You can use a query like this to find out duplicate records (`group by` all fields in your composite key):

```
select s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID, count(*)
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Components as c on c.BK_ID = a.[B-K no]
inner join CDB2020.dbo.Suppliers as s on s.Name = a.[Supplier 6]
group by s.Supplier_ID, c.BK_ID 
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: What does the min() and max() commands do? 
The problem is that the original Access DB is inconsistent with the data, and sometimes the same supplier have been listed as supplier 1, 2, 3, and so on, for the same component.

Comment: Let's say there are two records for a composite key combination, then the `group by` will combine the records into a single record, but if the value for `[Supplier 6 order no]` is different between those two records, the DMBS doesn't know which one to pick, so it requires us to pick one, so I just used `min` `max` for demonstration.

Comment: Just looking at your table structure, are you sure the composite key is correct? Can a `Supplier_ID` and `BK_ID` combination not supply more than one `Part_ID`?

Comment: It should not be able to supply more than one Part_ID, since this ID is unique for the supplier and component. The Part_ID is listed in the Access DB as order no.

Comment: See my edit, you may want to insert all records in one go using a `union`, which should ensure there are no duplicates.